# Loading data from a json file with an Interface

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm writing a little ionic app for learning purposes and I would like to load data from a json file and assign it to an Interface that describes the data. But I'm struggling with getting it the right way:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core"; 
import { HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";

export interface PhonebookEntry {
    name:           string,
    telephone:      string, 
    description:    string
}

@Component({
    selector:    'page-phonebook',
    templateUrl: 'phonebook.html'
})
export class PhonebookPage {

    entries: Array<PhonebookEntry>;

    constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
        this.load_entries('assets/json/phonebook.json');
    };

    load_entries(filePath: string) {
        return this.http.get(filePath)
            .subscribe(
                data => this.entries = data
            );
    };

}
```

I think only the line `data => this.entries = data` is wrong (also the IDE is telling me that), but I don't know to do this right and can't find documentation describing the correct way. If there actually is some I would be glad to know where I can find ressources about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

subscribe return the response as an object, not as an array. So `entries` type should be changed.

```
entries: PhonebookEntry;
```

In the subscribe, need to assign a type for response data.

```
load_entries(filePath: string) {
    return this.http.get(filePath)
        .subscribe(
            (data: PhonebookEntry) => this.entries = data // or use any type
        );
};
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-itqrki?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)